# List.Distinct() and == not using my equality comparison

Tags: c#

I am trying to make several operations use the same comparison method but I have been unable to get all of them to use it.  In the following code I put a breakpoint to check which of the operations are using it. My results show that while List.Contains() does use it, List.Distinct() and "==" do not.

How can I make all 3 of them use my equality comparison?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<TestObject> list1 = new List<TestObject>();
                list1.Add(new TestObject("test1"));
                list1.Add(new TestObject("test1"));
                List<TestObject> list2 = list1.Distinct().ToList();
                if (list1[0] == list1[1]) { }
                if (list2.Contains(list1[0])){ }
            }
        }
        class TestObject: IEquatable<TestObject>
        {
            string name;
            public TestObject(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public bool Equals(TestObject other)
            {
                return this.name == other.name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx): _The IComparable<T> interface defines the CompareTo method, which determines the sort order of instances of the implementing type. The IEquatable<T> interface defines the Equals method, which determines the equality of instances of the implementing type._

Comment: also [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx): _If you implement IEquatable<T>, you should also override the base class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IEnumerable<T>`, `Distinct` uses the default `IEquatableComparer<T>` comparer (unless you pass your own comparer). Internally this relies on `GetHashCode` to perform equality checks, where as `Contains` uses `Equals` hence why they don't yield the same results.

It's generally recommended you override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` when implementing your own custom equality checks anyway, see [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and == Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Would it be safe to simply add                                                                   `public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.name.GetHashCode();
        }`                                                                                                             in the TestObject class?  It seems to work from initial testing

Comment: @Alex in your case it should be fine, however, you should be aware that [String.GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) does have limitations (see the Remarks section in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

== is normally used to determine whether two references are the same. If you want to change this behavior for your class then you need to override the == operator as per the instructions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you, Does Distinct also need to be overrided?

Comment: I think doing hashcode, equals, and the == operator should get you what you need.